# Drools Execution Server pointing to Guvnor repository

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am trying to invoke a drools execution server (5.4.0) running on tomcat6, which is pointing to a previously created snapshot in Guvnor repository (.pkg file).

According to a tutorial I only have to edit the knowledge-service.xml file which is located in /webapps/drools-webapp/WEB-INF/classes of my execution server. Thereby a new resource that is pointing to the Guvnor repository should be added (see below):

```
<drools:kbase id="kbase1" node="node1">
      <drools:resources>
         <!--   <drools:resource  type="DRL" source="classpath:test.drl"/> -->
         <drools:resource  type="PKG" source="http://localhost:9080/guvnor-webapp/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/bonita/LATEST" basic-authentication="enabled"  />
    </drools:resources>
  </drools:kbase>
```

The URL is pointing to a snapshot that has been created with Guvnor and provides a .pkg-file.

Here the problem:

After I have invoked drools execution server I get an error message that looks like this:

Tomcat log:

```
INFO: Server startup in 4358 ms
31.10.2012 14:21:07 org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNUNG: WebApplicationException has been caught : bonita.BonitaPerson : bonita.BonitaPerson
---- Debugging information ----
message             : bonita.BonitaPerson
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : bonita.BonitaPerson
class               : org.drools.command.runtime.rule.InsertObjectCommand
required-type       : org.drools.command.runtime.rule.InsertObjectCommand
converter-type      : org.drools.runtime.help.impl.XStreamXML$InsertConverter
path                : /batch-execution/insert/bonita.BonitaPerson
line number         : 3
class[1]            : org.drools.command.runtime.BatchExecutionCommandImpl
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : null
-------------------------------
```

I think that the redirection from drools execution server to guvnor repository is not working and the class that is necessary is just not found. Even if I shut down my Guvnor server I get the same error message. To me the Guvnor server is never called by the drools execution server...

Can anybody help me to figure out how a proper redirection from drools to guvnor does look like?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have bonita.BonitaPerson class in the webapp lib folder?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I am there at the moment and certainly could use some help.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. Please see this post..
[drools-rest-cannotresolveclassexeption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695954/drools-rest-cannotresolveclassexception/16738333#16738333)

basically your  element is incorrect. It should look something like this:

```
<drools:resource  type="PKG" source="http://localhost:9080/guvnor-webapp/rest/package/bonita/LATEST" basic-authentication="enabled" username="admin" password="admin" />
```

- I don't have the reputation points to comment, so that is why I created an answer instead of comment.